# Дефис/тире/пробелы

Tags: орфография

Как правильно поставить знаки при указании начала и конца маршрута: Москва-Минск, Земля — Марс? А также промежутка времени: ноябрь-декабрь, весна — лето?

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах нужны тире, а не дефисы (см. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина, § 19: "Тире ставится между двумя (и более) словами, которые, сочетаясь друг с другом, означают пределы (значение «от.., до») — пространственные, временные, количественные...")